# Speed up Elasticsearch more like this query

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

Whats wrong with this more like this query? It was written from scratch. It returns relevant results, but it is too slow (this example took **187.9 ms**)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": ["similarity.analyzed"],
          "like": [{
            "_id": 4
          }, {
            "_id": 550
          }, {
            "_id": 757
          }],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "min_doc_freq": 1,
          "analyzer": "searchkick_search2",
          "minimum_should_match": "10%"
        }
      }, {
        "range": {
          "count_posts": {
            "gt": 0
          }
        }
      }],
      "must_not": [{
        "terms": {
          "_id": [4, 550, 757]
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

This query finds similar tags to given tags set.

similarity - text field, with all posts titles, joined with space.
count_posts - numeric field, which contains number of posts if each tag.

Running Elasticseach 7.8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 as single node. Rails 5 app with Searchkick gem.

Comment: How many documents do you have?

Comment: @Gibbs About 12K documents

Answer (score 0):

> Whats wrong with this more like this query?

```
"like": [{
            "_id": 4
          }, {
            "_id": 550
          }, {
            "_id": 757
          }]
```

It acts like `multi get` API. It does the below things.

1. Get's all the documents mentioned by `_id` in `like`
2. Analyse the `field` using `analyser` option ptovided
3. Analyse the same fields from the matching docs of step1. List of tokenizer,s filters also adds some `ms`.
4. Calculate doc, term frequencies along with min match.

And you have two more conditions.  Documentation says

> A more complicated use case consists of mixing texts with documents already existing in the index.

Unfortunately, I don't think this can be optimised further. But you can add a text instead id in `like` to make it much better. Hope the query is not always taking more than 100ms due to caching.

Comment: @Molfar did you get a chance to look at this?

Comment: Yes, but issue is still here. Replacing like documents with  text needs complex calculation too. I made this query following official docs. But it almost always takes more than 100 ms.